# around plugin error | too few to function ::resolve()

Tags: magento2, graphql, around-plugin

- This function runs around the resolve function for coupon api on Graphql,
- once the core function throws exception this function will catch and update the error message.

***core file [module-quote-graph-ql/Model/Resolver/ApplyCouponToCart.php]***

```
public function resolve(Field $field, $context, ResolveInfo $info, array $value = null, array $args = null)
   { ...
```

My around plugin code in correct namespace...

```
      public function aroundResolve(ApplyCouponToCart $subject, callable $proceed, $cartId, $result, $couponCode)
        {
           
            $result = false;
```

The Postman error im getting
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Refer Blow Code

```
public function aroundResolve(Field $subject, callable $proceed, $context, ResolveInfo $info, array $value = null, array $args = null)
    {
        //do something
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing to forward those agruments in your around function:

```
... Field $field, $context, ResolveInfo $info, array $value = null, array $args = null)
```

You can try:

```
public function aroundResolve(ApplyCouponToCart $subject, callable $proceed, Field $field, $context, ResolveInfo $info, array $value = null, array $args = null)
    {
       
        ...
    }
```

Or if you are not using/modifying the arguments, you could use variadics and argument unpacking to achieve this:

```
public function aroundResolve(ApplyCouponToCart $subject, callable $proceed, ...$args)
    {
       
        ...
    }
```